# Linked entities (OneToMany) not shown in Play2 Java form

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm having trouble with a Play! 2 form in which an object (a member of a neighbourhood association) containing two Lists (of persons in the household and of bank accounts) is edited. Weirdly, the list of persons is properly shown in the form while the textInputs of the bank accounts are empty in the form. The *number* of bank accounts is correct, though.

I added some debug statements in the edit form template to display the contents of the fields. For the field related to the list of Persons, it shows

```
BeanList size[2] hasMoreRows[false] list[models.Persoon@1, models.Persoon@2]
```

while for the list of bank accounts it shows

```
BeanList deferred
```

I've cut down the app as much as possible to isolate the issue, and pushed the code to Github (`git://github.com/janpascal/ledenadmin.git`) on branch `debug-form`. It seems both lists are created and handled exactly the same, but somehow show up differently. The relation is Cascade-ALL. Just to make sure I've tried adding `save()` and `update()` calls when creating the Person or Bankrekening objects, but that doesn't make a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The form:

```
@(id: Long, myForm: Form[Lid])

@main("Bewerk lid") {
    <h1>Bewerk lid</h1>

    @myForm
<br>
    @myForm.value()
<br>
    @myForm.field("personen").value()
<br>
    @myForm.field("rekeningnummers").value()
<br>

    @helper.form(action = routes.Leden.saveLid(id)) {
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Lid @id</legend>
    @helper.repeat(myForm("personen"), min = 1) { persoonField =>
            @helper.inputText(persoonField("name"), '_label -> "Naam" )
    }
    @helper.inputText(myForm("address"), '_label -> "Adres")

    @helper.repeat(myForm("rekeningnummers"), min = 1) { rekeningField =>
            @helper.inputText(rekeningField("rekeningnummer"))
    }
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Opslaan">
    }
}
```

My models:

```
@Entity
public class Lid extends Model {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="lid_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="lid_seq_gen", sequenceName="LID_SEQ")
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="lid")
    public List<Persoon> personen;

    public String address;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="lid")
    public List<Bankrekening> rekeningnummers;

    public Lid(Long id, String name, String address, String bankaccount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.personen = new ArrayList<Persoon>();
        this.personen.add(new Persoon(this, name));
        this.rekeningnummers = new ArrayList<Bankrekening>();
        this.rekeningnummers.add(new Bankrekening(this,bankaccount));
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Lid "+id+" ("+getFirstName()+")";
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        if(personen.size()>=1) return personen.get(0).name;
        return "";
    }

    public Bankrekening addRekening(String rekeningnummer) {
      Bankrekening rek = new Bankrekening(this, rekeningnummer);
      rekeningnummers.add(rek);
      return rek;
    }

    public static void create(Lid lid) {
        lid.save();
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
       find.ref(id).delete();
    }

    public static Finder<Long,Lid> find = new Finder<Long, Lid>(
            Long.class, Lid.class
          );
}


@Entity
public class Persoon extends Model {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="persoon_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="persoon_seq_gen", sequenceName="PERSOON_SEQ")
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Lid lid;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public Persoon(Lid lid, String name) {
        this.lid = lid; 
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void create(Persoon p) {
        p.save();
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
       find.ref(id).delete();
    }

    public static Finder<Long,Persoon> find = new Finder<Long, Persoon>(
            Long.class, Persoon.class
          );
}


@Entity
public class Bankrekening extends Model {

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="bankrek_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="bankrek_seq_gen", sequenceName="BANKREKENING_SEQ")
@Id
public Long id;

@ManyToOne
public Lid lid;

@Constraints.Required
public String rekeningnummer;

public Bankrekening(Lid lid, String nummer) {
    this.lid = lid;
    this.rekeningnummer = nummer;
}

public static void create(Bankrekening bankrekening) {
    bankrekening.save();
}

public static void delete(Long id) {
   find.ref(id).delete();
}

public static Finder<Long,Bankrekening> find = new Finder<Long, Bankrekening>(
        Long.class, Bankrekening.class
      );
```

}

The controller:

```
public class Leden extends Controller {

    public static Result lijst() {
        List<Lid> leden = Lid.find.all();
        return ok(ledenlijst.render(leden));
    }

    public static Result bewerkLid(Long id) {
        Form<Lid> myForm = form(Lid.class).fill(Lid.find.byId(id));
        Lid lid = Lid.find.byId(id);
        System.out.println("Editing "+lid.toString());
        System.out.print("Bankrekeningen:");
        for(Bankrekening rek: lid.rekeningnummers) {
            System.out.print(" "+rek.rekeningnummer);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Form information:");
        System.out.println(myForm.value());
        System.out.println(myForm);
        System.out.println(myForm.data());
        return ok(editlid.render(id, myForm));
    }

    public static Result saveLid(Long id) {
        Form<Lid> form = form(Lid.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(form.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(editlid.render(id,form));
        }
        form.get().update(id);
        System.out.println("Form information:");
        System.out.println(form.value());
        System.out.println(form);
        System.out.println(form.data());
        Lid lid = form.get();
        System.out.println("Updating"+lid.toString());
        System.out.print("    Bankrekeningen:");
        for(Bankrekening rek: lid.rekeningnummers) {
            System.out.print(" "+rek.rekeningnummer);
        }
        return lijst();
    }

}
```

And finally the Global object seeding the database:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        InitialData.insert(app);
    }

    static class InitialData {

        public static void insert(Application app) {
            if(Ebean.find(Lid.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Seeding members");
                for(long i=1; i<10; i++) {
                  Lid lid = new Lid(i, "lid"+i, "Kerkstraat "+i, "Bank account"+i);
                  //lid.addRekening(new Long(i*5462).toString());
                  Lid.create(lid);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried Play 2.1.2-RC1 and that seems to have fixed this issue.

Comment: Reverting to 2.1.1. while cleaning the target/ and precompiled/ folders and the issue remains solved. Which also mean I can't reproduce any more.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a dirty Play project somehow, at least cleaning up both the Play installation and the project itself helped.